# Simple Client Server communication

Tags: java, sockets

I am learning currently about client server communication using Java through sockets.
First of all I retrieve my own machine's IP Address using following code.

```
InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
//the result being 192.168.56.1
```

Now I write the simple client server application using the above mentioned address as follow

```
public class SimpleClientServer {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //sending "Hello World" to the server
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try
    {

        clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.56.1", 16000);

        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                 clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        out.println("Hello World");

        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error occured " + e);

    }
}
}
```

The result hower reads a follow.

```
Error occured java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

What is the reason for this. Is it just the wrong host address?

Comment: Well what do you expect to be *listening* on port 16000?

Comment: First setup a server socket at port 16000 on the same machine, and then run the same code

Comment: 1) Please tell us the line where the error occur
2) Please show the server code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you have given you seem to suggest that there is currently nothing listening on port 16000 for the socket to connect to.

If this is the case you need to implement something like

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(16000);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 16000.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

More information can be found in [the Java online documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) and [a full example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java) is included.

Answer (score 2):

With sockets, no matter what language you're using, you either initiate a connection with socket_connect or you listen and accept with socket_listen and socket_accept. Your socket_connect call is trying to connect to an ip address that doesn't seem to be listening to anything.

Comment: I'm afraid that the `Socket` constructor does the connection in this case. On the other end, a `ServerSocket` is needed, which you would invoke the `accept()` method upon to receive a `Socket` endpoint.

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate the functionality.

Comment: I just saw the last bit of your answer (oops) ;) You're correct.